# Reset cursor position after ResultSet updateRow

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

For some reason, the Oracle JDBC driver may move the `ResultSet` cursor somewhere else (not to the same row, and not to the next row) when `updateRow` is called (I am also inserting and deleting rows). How can I avoid this problem?

Note: The results are ordered by the primary key of the table (I've specified this in the SQL). But I'm increasingly suspecting that the "order by" clause is not working properly.

Comment: To where do you want to reset the cursor?

Comment: Just a thought: Are you selecting `for update`? I know the code samples don't show it but the approach used in PL/SQL or through other APIs is to open a cursor as select `for update` and then to update `where current of <cursor>`. I would assume that Oracle does this "under the covers".

Comment: the "next row" is defined by your order by clause.  Can you setup a simple pl/sql block to open a cursor and loop through rows?  You should find the results to be in the same order as through jdbc driver (at least easy enough to test this).  If you need a sample pl/sql code, let me know

Comment: It appears that the real error is that [the select query is returning a resultset with some results missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516163/oracle-order-by-clause-returning-results-in-wrong-order-or-with-results-missin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to user error. I had another copy of the application running on a different machine, which I had forgotten about, and that was changing the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

No where in the documentation says that after an `updateRow` operation the cursor is moved to the next row...

Sources:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm
2. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update
3. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse4.htm
4. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateRow%28%29

Comment: The code samples in your second and third links strongly imply that it stays on the same row - at least, when only updates are performed - otherwise the code samples wouldn't make sense. But it doesn't always stay on the same row. Besides, this does not actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Forward only updatable result sets** maintains a cursor which can only move in one direction (forward), and also update rows. This has to be created with concurrency mode `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` and type `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

**Note**: The default type is `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

**Visibility of changes**
After an update or delete is made on a forward only result set, the result set's cursor is no longer on the row just updated or deleted, but immediately before the next row in the result set (it is necessary to move to the next row before any further row operations are allowed). This means that changes made by `ResultSet.updateRow()` and `ResultSet.deleteRow()` are never visible.
If a row has been inserted, i.e using `ResultSet.insertRow()` it may be visible in a forward only result set.

**Conflicting operations**
The current row of the result set cannot be changed by other transactions, since it will be locked with an update lock. Result sets held open after a commit have to move to the next row before allowing any operations on it.

Some conflicts may prevent the result set from doing updates/deletes:
If the current row is deleted by a statement in the same transaction, calls to `ResultSet.updateRow()` will cause an exception, since the cursor is no longer positioned on a valid row.

Comment: That is the documentation for "JavaDB", which is a DBMS that is bundled with the JDK. I am not sure that is applicable to all DBMSs?