# Oracle "order by" clause returning results in wrong order or with results missing

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

In my application logs, I can see that the query results are being iterated over (using a JDBC ResultSet, nothing fancy), and certain results which are actually in the table, are either missing, or appear too late in the resultset (I'm not sure which, because I often get a primary key violation before I hit the end if this happens).

My query is:

```
select t.* from myschema.vm t order by id;
```

However **I can't see this issue occurring when I run the exact same query in SQL Developer** (while the database is not changing), and it only occurs about half the time in my application (I suspect it sometimes doesn't happen due to the table changing due to all the inserts and updates).

Other key points to mention:

1. I'm doing updates, inserts and potentially deletes using another database connection, while I'm iterating over the ResultSet. However, this shouldn't matter, right?
2. I'm using BoneCP for connection pooling.
3. The database encoding is AL32UTF8.

Why is this happening? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: What is the datatype of the `id` column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name varchar2(64)

Comment: Are you specifying anything for `resultSetType` or `resultSetConcurrency`?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes, it's now `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY`. In a previous StackOverflow question of mine related to this problem, it was different, but it's now using these.

Comment: So there are no concurrent updates/inserts/deletes on this table? If there can be concurrent updates on this table then you should be using `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`.

Comment: I suspect you are actually storing numbers in that character column and now you are surprised that `'10'` comes before `'2'`. This is because you are storing numbers the wrong way. You should store them in a `NUMBER` column and then the sorting will be correct.

Comment: @Colin'tHart No, there are concurrent updates/inserts/deletes, but using another connection, which according to my reading of the docs and the JDBC Tutorial, shouldn't require `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, the entries are alphanumeric hostnames, and the ordering problems I have encountered all relate to letters, not digits.

Comment: When you say you get a primary key violation, what operation as you trying to perform, specifically?

Comment: If you don't see the problem running the query itself, then good chance your issue is how you grab/store/iterate these values via java.  But you only show the query, so you'll probably have to post the java code

Comment: I think you might need `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` to avoid seeing changes to the underlying recordset.

Comment: Replacing `id` with `NLSSORT(id, 'NLS_SORT = UNICODE_BINARY')` in the query seems to have fixed this; both the application and SQL Developer get correct results back from the query. I'm guessing it works by avoiding using the index. But why is this necessary?

Comment: I spoke too soon - it happened again, even with the `NLSSORT` change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to user error. I had another copy of the application running on a different machine, which I had forgotten about, and that was changing the database at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle resultsets are freezed in the moment you execute the query, no matter how later you fetch the data (or part of them); so, if other session inserts data, you will found (rightly ordered) only rows already committed when you open the cursor.

Also, I suspect you create your ID with some evaluation on current values found on the table instead of using a sequence or a shared atomic counter, so you get the PK violation.

Comment: No, I don't create the ID, these are not generated keys, they are hostnames that already exist in reality.

Comment: And this doesn't explain the issue: these are results that exist continuously, before, after, and during the iteration.

Comment: You wrote "I'm doing updates, inserts and potentially deletes using another database connection, while I'm iterating over the ResultSet."

The point is: are you sure "missing" results are really there when you open your cursor? How you assert they should be there?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I am logging everything using the JDBC driver's own logging mechanism.